# Dictionry write to file by values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, dictionary

I need to write Dictionray to a file, by values to keys. meaning if I have for exemple dictionary of movies(=keys), and the actors who palyed that movie, I need to write to a file an actor and then write all the movies he played in.

the keys are movies, the values are set of actors.

I mannaged to write movies and values, but as explained that is not what I want.

the file should be like:
Actor Name, Movie1,Movie2 etc...

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward thing to do is to invert the dictionary.

```
actor2movies = {}
for movie, actors in movie2actors.items():
    for actor in actors:
        if actor not in actor2movies:
            actor2movies[actor] = []
        actor2movies[actor].append(movie)
```

(If you initialize `actor2movies` to `collections.defaultdict(list)` instead, you can omit the `if` statement.)

Then write the resulting dictionary out, one key and its values at a time.

```
with open("foo.txt", "w") as f:
    for actor, movies in actor2movies.items():
        print("{},{}".format(actor, ",".join(movies))
```